# How to do something on an specific position of a recyclerView adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to do something on position 0 of an adapter onBindViewHolder method.
The code is shown below:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int position) {
        if(position == 0)
        {
            myViewHolder.transparentBlackView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        Picasso.with(context).load(urlList.get(position)).into(myViewHolder.pictureImageView);
        transparentViewList.add(myViewHolder.transparentBlackView);
        myViewHolder.positionTextView.setText(position+"");
    }
```

But I don't know why code inside if block (myViewHolder.transparentBlackView.setVisibility(View.GONE);) runs on position 9 too?

Can someone help me?

Comment: add else part thats it

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `else` part too.

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int position) {
    if(position == 0)
    {
        myViewHolder.transparentBlackView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else{
   myViewHolder.transparentBlackView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    Picasso.with(context).load(urlList.get(position)).into(myViewHolder.pictureImageView);
    transparentViewList.add(myViewHolder.transparentBlackView);
    myViewHolder.positionTextView.setText(position+"");
}
```

Comment: It worked. But I don't understand why I need else part?

Comment: Because Same ViewHolder will be return for next position and you just made it `GONE` so it will be `GONE` forever without an else part . Pls accept the answer then .Thx

Comment: You said next position but I said it also runs code inside if  block  at position 9. I don't understand what happens.

Comment: The `If` code will not call for 1-9 position only called for 0th . Try to put Log inside if and else . then see .